# How to set the cursor in the beginning of the page with r package officer?

Tags: r, cursor, officer

I'm inserting several paragraphs in a word document and the space between paragraphs must be two empty lines. As predict, sometimes one or two paragraphs are positioned at the beginning of a page. In these cases, I need to remove these empty paragraphs.

Does someone have any suggestion?

I was thinking to detect empty lines in the beginning of each page and remove them.

Comment: What do you mean by *"two empty paragraphs"*? Did you mean to say two empty lines?

Comment: exactly, I just wanted to emphasize that these two empty lines I added as paragraph with officer "body_add_par(doc, "")"

Comment: I am not very adept at `officer` but I don't see a way to detect pages. The idea that I had was looping through the pages and remove the empty lines.

Comment: The problem is that I just need to remove empty lines in the beginning of each page... the other ones I must to keep. Thank you for your attention anyway :)

Comment: I understood. I meant to loop through the pages and **remove the empty lines at the beginning of *each page***. But after a lot of searching, I don't see any functions that would break the document into pages or would tell us where (what page) each paragraph is located. If you can find a way to identify the page number for each paragraph, then that can be added to document summary, and where we have a new page and empty lines, we remove those, while keeping other empty lines.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually adjusting this, have you considered changing the paragraph style for all your paragraphs such that there's a 2 x (whatever your chosen font size is) space after each paragraph? This way, the spacing will appear within the same page, but not at the top of a new page.

```
# Note: the following assumes you already have a document with content. If you
# are creating from scratch, you should be able to apply the desired paragraph 
# style whenever you add a new paragraph, using body_add_par.

library(officer)
library(dplyr)

# load file
dd <- read_docx("sample.docx")

# check the name of the style currently used in the document (default should be 'Normal')
View(docx_summary(dd)) 

# optional: check all existing styles in the document & their names
# View(styles_info(dd))  

# define new paragraph style that adds 40pt spacing after each paragraph
# (assuming font size of 20pt, this is equivalent to two empty lines)
dd <- dd %>%
  docx_set_paragraph_style(style_id = "Normal1", style_name = "Normal1",
                           fp_p = fp_par(padding.bottom = 2 * 20)) 

# for all paragraphs that use one or more old styles, change their style reference
# to the newly created style with large spacing after each paragraph
dd <- dd %>% change_styles(mapstyles = list(
  "Normal1" = c("Normal") # new style = c(old style 1, old style 2, ...)
))

# optional: confirm that the desired paragraphs have changed their styles
# View(docx_summary(dd)) 

# save result
print(dd, "new.docx")
```

Sample dataset (I used the starwars dataset as the basis for creating random chunks of text since it's readily available as part of the dplyr package):

```
doc <- read_docx()

sample.text <- paste(unlist(unname(starwars)), collapse = " ") %>%
  substring(., 
            first = seq(1, nchar(.), by = 1000), 
            last = c(seq(1000, nchar(.), by = 1000), nchar(.)))

for(i in seq_along(sample.text)) {
  doc <- doc %>%
    body_add_par(value = sample.text[[i]])
}

print(doc, "sample.docx")

rm(i, doc, sample.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was simple and effective! Cheers! :)